# After ajax passing data to php, page will not loading for the first entry, but still loading for the rest

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

In my webpage, I want to show all the items fetched form server, and under each item, their is a "Complete" button. When press the compete button, the id of the item will be send to a php file. The code for my form is:

```
<?php 
    $x = $NumberofItems;
    while ($x > 0) :
?>  

<p><i class="fa fa-question" style="color:#ffff00"></i> On <?php echo htmlspecialchars($date_Quest[$x])?>: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($desc_Quest[$x])?></p>
<form id="formQuestComplete" action="quest-complete.php" method="post" style="display: inline-block;">
    <input type="hidden" name="QuestID" value="<?php echo $id_Quest[$x]; ?>"/>
    <button id="subQuestComplete" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Complete</button> 
</form>

<?php       
    $x--;
    endwhile;
?>
```

And my jquery code is :

```
$("#subQuestComplete").click( function() {
$.post( $("#formQuestComplete").attr("action"),
    $("#formQuestComplete :input").serializeArray(),
    function(info){ $("#result").html(info);
    });
});

$("#formQuestComplete").submit( function() {
    return false;
});
```

For example, when I have 10 items listed by the form, only the first item will send data and stay on the same page. All the rest will send data, but then redirect to the php page.

Comment: You're creating multiple items with the same id and id's ***must*** be unique in a web page. If they're not unique you'll get funny results like the first link working, but the others not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your PHP code to make sure item is given a class, instead of an id (*because id's must be unique* or they will not be handled correctly) -

```
<?php 
    $x = $NumberofItems;
    while ($x > 0) :
?>  

<p><i class="fa fa-question" style="color:#ffff00"></i> On <?php echo htmlspecialchars($date_Quest[$x])?>: <?php echo htmlspecialchars($desc_Quest[$x])?></p>
<form class="formQuestComplete" action="quest-complete.php" method="post" style="display: inline-block;">
    <input type="hidden" name="QuestID" value="<?php echo $id_Quest[$x]; ?>"/>
    <button class="subQuestComplete" class="btn btn-default btn-xs">Complete</button> 
</form>

<?php       
    $x--;
    endwhile;
?>
```

Then change your jQuery to handle the clicks appropriately (you do not have a submit, so eliminate the last function you show)-

```
$(".subQuestComplete").click( function(e) { // handle the button click
    e.preventDefault(); // prevent the click's default action
    var thisForm = $(this).parent('form'); // get this form
    var thisData = $(this).parent('form').find('input').val();
    $.post( 
        $(thisForm).attr("action"),
        {QuestID: thisData}, // no need to serialize for a one value form
        function(info){ 
            $("#result").html(info);
    });
});
```

Since the elements are now identified by class with can traverse the DOM tree to find the form value(s) for each form respctively - regardless of how many there may be in the page.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Working perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your code like this:

`.click( function(e) { e.preventDefault();`
after this, the rest of your code.

If you dont do this, then the original click event handler also will run. after a time.

So your code should look like this:

```
$("#subQuestComplete").click( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.post( $("#formQuestComplete").attr("action"), $("#formQuestComplete :input").serializeArray(),function(info){ 
        $("#result").html(info);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you. But it doesn't work. I added e.preventDefault(); but everything still stays the same. When click the button under the first item, it will not redirect. When click the button under other items, it redirected.

Comment: The OP is using `return false;` which will prevent the redirect - but only on the first item because the id's are not unique.

Comment: Ah really. Should change to classes.